# MVC ASP.net session is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, null

I have the following code which was ok until someone else put some other code in the site which sorta mucks it up now.

This is my code:

```
var existingContext = HttpContext.Current;
var writer = new StringWriter();
var response = new HttpResponse(writer);
var context = new HttpContext(existingContext.Request, response) { User = existingContext.User };
HttpContext.Current = context;
HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Default);
HttpContext.Current.Session["Test"] = "test";
for (Int32 i = 0; i < existingContext.Session.Count; i++)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(existingContext.Session.Keys[i], existingContext.Session[i]);
}
```

The idea behind this is to be able to capture the output of a view and render it to pdf. Now my only issue is that when i assign context back to HttpContext.Current, the session is null. I need to be able to initialize the session so that i can assign variables into it.

i will also add that this is inside a static class

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
```

Any clues?

Comment: sorry the code view thing mucked up a bit or i did something wrong the code should be:

Comment: var existingContext = HttpContext.Current;
var writer = new StringWriter();
var response = new HttpResponse(writer);
var context = new HttpContext(existingContext.Request, response) { User = existingContext.User };
HttpContext.Current = context;
HttpContext.Current.Session["Test"] = "test";
for (Int32 i = 0; i < existingContext.Session.Count; i++)
{
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(existingContext.Session.Keys[i], existingContext.Session[i]);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have solved the issue for now and that was to remove the lines:

```
            var context = new HttpContext(existingContext.Request, response) { User = existingContext.User };
        HttpContext.Current = context;
        HttpContext.Current.Request.
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < existingContext.Session.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(existingContext.Session.Keys[i], existingContext.Session[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is occurring inside of an HttpHandler, you need to add the IRequiresSessionState interface to your handler for the session to be available -

```
public class HttpPdfWriteHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState {
     [...]
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx

Comment: unfortunately this is occurring inside a static class

public static class ControllerExtensions

Comment: i got the original code from: http://www.jimzimmerman.com/blog/2009/10/06/PdfResult+A+Custom+ActionResult+In+ASPNET+MVC.aspx

and http://jamesmcc.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/pdfresult-a-custom-actionresult-in-asp-net-mvc2-updated/

Answer (score 0):

1) Start–> Administrative Tools –> Services

2) right click over the ASP.NET State Service and click “start”

*additionally you could set the service to automatic so that it will work after a reboot.

For more details you can check my blog post: http://jamshidhashimi.com/2011/03/16/unable-to-make-the-session-state-request-to-the-session-state-server/
ref:
[Unable to make the session state request to the session state server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376717/unable-to-make-the-session-state-request-to-the-session-state-server)