# ASP.NET MVC Session variables become null through HTML.Action ChildAction

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I'm developing a simple test website using ASP.NET MVC3 and Razor syntax. It has `_LayoutPage.cshtml` as master template which uses `@HTML.Action` to print user id at the top of the site for each page.

I implemented a `childAction` named `userInfo` for this partial view which reads the user id from `HTTPContext.Session` and prints it out. The child action is implemented in a controller called `CommonActionController` derived from `Controller`. In addition to user id it also reads two more variables from session and prints it.

```
public class CommonActionController: Controller
{

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult userInfo()
    {

        if(HTTPContext.Session["x-user-id"] != null)
        {
            ViewBag.UserId = (string)(HTTPContext.Session["x-user-id"]);
            ViewBag.UserFirstName = (string)(HTTPContext.Session["x-user-first-name"]);
            ViewBag.UserLastName = (string)(HTTPContext.Session["x-user-last-name"]);
            ViewBag.UserLoggedinSince = (DateTime)(HTTPContext.Session["x-user-logon-timestamp"]).ToString("f");
        }

        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

My main page controller called `HomeController` has the dashboard functionality implemented in `Dashboard` action (currently it just prints the word "Dashboard"). In this controller I have overridden `Controller.OnActionExecuting()` method which validates that the user id exists in session. It reads total three variables from session just like the aforementioned childAction.

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{


    public HomeController()
    {

    }


    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx)
    {


        base.OnActionExecuting(ctx);

        if(HTTPContext.Session["x-user-id"] == null)
            ctx.Result = new RedirectResult("logon/userlogon");

        if(HTTPContext.Session["x-user-logon-timestamp"] == null)
            ctx.Result = new RedirectResult("logon/userlogon");

        if(HTTPContext.Session["x-user-internal-flag"] == null)
            ctx.Result = new RedirectResult("logon/userlogon");

    }

    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        // nothing to see here
        return View();
    }

}
```

I have cleaned up the code little bit to remove the debug.print statements.

As per the logs I see that the `OnActionExecuting()` method and `userInfo` child action are invoked simultaneously. At one point `OnActionExecuting()` gets nulls for session variables. In the log I can see that until the point `ChildAction` is invoked, session variables hold their value within `OnActionExecuting()`. Once the `childaction` accesses them, they become null.

When I comment the code that accesses session from child action, everything works fine. What am I doing wrong? Is there some precaution I have to take while accessing session variables? Is this due to my ignorance about how to access Session asynchronously?

I also have following in my `web.config`:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Comment: please provide the code.

Comment: Attached code. Sorry should have done it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

1) Start–> Administrative Tools –> Services

2) right click over the ASP.NET State Service and click “start”

*additionally you could set the service to automatic so that it will work after a reboot.

For more details you can check my blog post: http://jamshidhashimi.com/2011/03/16/unable-to-make-the-session-state-request-to-the-session-state-server/

ref:
[Unable to make the session state request to the session state server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376717/unable-to-make-the-session-state-request-to-the-session-state-server)