# Can´t set sessionState mode to StateServer

Tags: c#, webforms, session-state

We are a group working on a web form application. We have set the application sessionState mode to StateServer in web.config file.

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" timeout="40" stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424" cookieless="false"></sessionState>
```

But for two of us when we try to run the application we are getting this exception :

> Unable to make the session state request to the session state server.
>   Please ensure that the ASP.NET State service is started and that the
>   client and server ports are the same.  If the server is on a remote
>   machine, please ensure that it accepts remote requests by checking the
>   value of
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection.
>   If the server is on the local machine, and if the before mentioned
>   registry value does not exist or is set to 0, then the state server
>   connection string must use either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' as the
>   server name.

We are using .NET Framework 4.0. The process ASP .NET State Service is running on the default port 42424.

Somebody know what is wrong ?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I have tested all suggestions on this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376717/unable-to-make-the-session-state-request-to-the-session-state-server) but no changes. And i can see that **aspnet_state service is running on port 42424**

Comment: Can you telnet to localhost on port 42424?   I like to use telnet to troubleshoot connectivity issues.  If you get an error trying to connect you have an issue with the service or firewall.  If you get a blinking cursor or gibberish back then the connectivity is good, and you can focus on 'higher-level' problems

Comment: I get Connection to Host is lost