# Unable to make the session state request to the session state server . error code=0x80072749

Tags: asp.net, web-config, session-state, stateserver, session-state-server

I am seeing an error on my production machine. The application is working fine for a while then suddenly it's not responding and I fix it by restarting IIS.

StateServer is running fine in Services and the mode is automatic.

The string below is what I'm using in web.config:

```
<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" stateNetworkTimeout="60" timeout="2" useHostingIdentity="false" compressionEnabled="false">
```

Unable to make the session state request to the session state server. Details: last phase='Sending request to the state server', error code=0x80072749, size of outgoing data=0

HttpException:

> Unable to make the session state request to the session state server.
>   Please ensure that the ASP.NET State service is started and that the
>   client and server ports are the same. If the server is on a remote
>   machine, please ensure that it accepts remote requests by checking the
>   value of
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection.
>   If the server is on the local machine, and if the before mentioned
>   registry value does not exist or is set to 0, then the state server
>   connection string must use either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' as the
>   server name.

Answer (score 1):

Go to services, start ASP.NET State service. 
Then check the key is true :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection
```

Comment: its already started. my application working fine for 20 minutes having 50 + concurrent users.

Comment: allow remote connection is also true in registry.

Answer (score 0):

This post on SO suggests quite a few things you can look at.

[Unable to make the session state request to the session state server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376717/unable-to-make-the-session-state-request-to-the-session-state-server)

Comment: checked everything in mentioned post also .. but no luck still getting same error after 15 - 20 minutes.